# How can I kill processes according to their name?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a way to kill processes according to their name ('job_runner_').
this is what i currently do, i run the following command:
`ps -ef |grep job_runner_` and then run `kill -9` on each on of the processes returned (there could be several processes returned).

How can I do it on a single command?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the processes I'm trying to kill have the following names: `job_runner_0`, `job_runner_1`, `job_runner_2` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`killall` that is mentioned is in the `psmisc` package (named so in Debian based installations at least). Another alternative is `pkill` that is in the `procps` package.

---

You should use a tool that is made for this purpose. If you really, really, really want to do it by parsing `ps` output, you could do something like

```
ps -ao pid,comm | awk '/job_runner_/{system("kill "$1)}'
```

Comment: A worthwhile note here in case you find yourself on another Unix-like operating system besides Linux. This usage of killall is largely a linux-ism, some other flavors of Unix have the System V derived version of killall (which is installed as killall5 on Linux systems). The SysV-derived killall is of course a bit aggressive, literally killing every process on the system except the login of the user running it. Always check man pages before running commands on strange systems.

Comment: In that vein: `pkill` (and `pgrep`) originally comes from Solaris 7 and are standard there. The Linux versions are made to be fully compatible.

Comment: `ps -ao pid,comm | awk '/job_runner_/{system("kill "$1)}'` didnt killed the processes...

Comment: @Ran: Do some testing yourself. What does the first part of the command give you? I.e., if you remove the `| awk ...` bit, what is the output? It should be the PIDs and names of the processes.

Comment: @Ran: For that matter, why don't you use `pkill` as I recommend?  After installing `procps` you can test your search command with the program `pgrep` first. `pgrep job_runner_` should return all PIDs, and exchanging `pgrep` with `pkill` will kill them.

Comment: here is the output of the first part of the command and the output of the command im tunning: http://pastebin.com/AquKvHtc

Comment: @Ran: Weird `ps` output. What OS are you on (Red Hat/Debian/etc)?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

[killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) will do this for you.

> Name
>
> killall - kill processes by name

Note that the `-r` option will interpret the name as a regexp and thus satisfy your requirement to kill multiple similarly named processes.

Note also that it's preferable not to kill processes immediately by using the -9 option. Instead a normal kill should be used since it'll give the process a chance to catch that signal, perform any cleanup and then exit cleanly. Using -9 won't let the process do that, and should only be used for troublesome/unresponsive processes.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with [killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

```
killall --regexp ^job_runner.*
```

Comment: when I run it i get `job_runner: no process found` I guess that because the processes names are: `job_runner_0`, `job_runner_1`, `job_runner_2`... how can I make a more generic call?

Comment: @Ran How about `killall --regexp job_runner.*`?

Comment: getting: `no process found`

Comment: @Ran I just ran a test in an Ubuntu VM. First, I started `tail -f /somefile &` and then I ran `killall --regexp ^ta.*` and it killed the process. The `^` is not required, but helpful. This way it only kills the process when it **starts** with `ta`. Otherwise it'll try to kill a **lot** of processes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pkill job_runner_`.

You can also check for processes by name with `pgrep job_runner_`.

Comment: it doesnt kill the processes with name: `job_runner_1`, `job_runner_2` etc

Comment: ? I think it should. I just tried with a simple example and in fact it does work for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
ps -ef | grep job_runner_ | xargs kill -9
```

Try this one.

Comment: got the following: ERROR: garbage process ID "job_runner_".

Comment: This won't work. Look at what output is sent to `xargs` - that is not a PID. Don't do it this way, use tools that are meant for this, e.g. `pkill` or `killall` that have been proposed.